# How can i fix this code in order to check if a number is palindrome, using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, numbers, palindrome

I am quite new to C. I don't really understand how to get the pointers right. I know it can be done without pointers , but I have to use them

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void palindrome(int *n)
{
   int ok=0,*p,*m;
    m=n;
    while(*n!=0)
    {
        *p=*p*10+*n%10;
        *n=*n/10;
    }
    if (*m==*p) ok=1;
    if (*m!=*p) ok=0;

    if (ok==1)
        printf("Number is palindrome.");
    if (ok==0)
        printf("Number is not palindrome");
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Give value to n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    palindrome(n);


}
```

The expected resut would be , for example, number 212 is palindrome, number 312 is not palindrome

Comment: To format the code correctly: paste the code, select the code, press the code button `{}`. Try it now by clicking on the [edit] link underneath the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. I think you should try and understand how pointers work before actually using them. I didn't want to provide you the code, but since you are new, i am providing a working code. Try understand how it is working instead of just copy pasting this code to where ever you have to put.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void palindrome(int *n)
{
   int ok=0;
   int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
   int *m = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *p=0;
    *m=*n;
    while(*n!=0)
    {
        *p=*p*10+*n%10;
        *n=*n/10;
    }
    if (*m==*p) ok=1;
    if (*m!=*p) ok=0;

    if (ok==1)
        printf("Number is palindrome.");
    if (ok==0)
        printf("Number is not palindrome");
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Give value to n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    palindrome(&n);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@arpit-agrawal

You forgot to add free, at the end of

```
void palindrome(int *n)
{
    ...
    free(p);
    free(m);
}
```